# Captcha CSS style override

Tags: css, captcha

I have a captcha on my site and I think the style is being overridden by some other css as you can see below at the bottom of the captcha it is a bit off..

[image: Captcha]

What is the best way to spot CSS overrides in firebug? Been looking at this for a while now and cant seem to figure out where the problem lies..

Thanks

Rick

Comment: Can you post a live link and I can take a look?

Comment: sorry the site isn't live, my client also wouldn't want me posting it live.. Any tips for spotting the problem though?

Comment: Based on the image above it looks like there's a height or overflow issue.  Maybe padding/margin space also.

Few things you can try...  If I'm not mistaken there is a CSS file associated with the recaptcha plugin, make sure that CSS file is the "last" CSS file to be hooked up.  This will ensure that it's styles will overwrite other styles for it's specific block.

Other than that, use chrome dev tools or firebug to inspect the individual elements.  "Untick" certain rules and watch to see what happens when you do.  Any rules that have a strikethrough are rules that have been overwritten.

Comment: Thanks couldn't find any overwriting styles but I was able to fix the issue by adding a height value to the container and then applying overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

So.. Couldn't find any overriding styles but managed to fix it by adding a height to the containing div and then adding overflow:hidden, looking perfect now!